# Кодировка Word в редакторе VScode

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, python-docx

Как изменить кодировку ".docx" на utf-8 или надо по-другому что-то делать?

```
from docx import Document

document = Document()
document.save('test.docx')
```

Сам вопрос как исправить:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А какой результат вы ожидаете? Вообще-то VSCode не умеет и вряд ли когда-нибудь научится открывать вордовые файлы. Потому что это не его задача. Для вордовых файлов есть ворд.

Comment: Мне он нужен для сохранения или редактирования вордового файла

Comment: Ну питон сохранил вам вордовый файл. Зачем вы его хотите открыть редактором кода вместо ворда?

Answer (score 4):

VS Code работает с простыми текстовыми файлами. DOCX же – это формат документов для работы в Microsoft Word, внутренее состоящий из архива с XML-файлами как для самого текста, так и внутренних параметров.

Такие форматы, как DOCX, могут быть открыты для редактирования только специальными редакторами, вроде Microsoft Word или LibreOffice Writer.

Самый максимум, что можно найти для VS Code, это расширение для просмотра DOCX (и других форматов) в приложении:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cweijan.vscode-office

Но лучше для таких форматов использовать приложения, которые для них предназначены.